# SQL Server find the row before the data has changed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data where there could be 2 pieces of data that can change.

The **SerNo** and the **Condition**.

I need to be able to detect the which one changes first and return the row above the change.

In the example below:

- **Condition** changes @ `TransID = 5`
- **SerNo** changes @ `TransID = 7`

Since **Condition** changes first, I would need to return the row above which is `TransID = 4`.

| TransID | Part | SerNo | IN_Nr | OUT_Nr | OrderNr | Type | Condition |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123-1 | abc123 | 232753 | 232233 | 888777 | OUT | NEW |
| 2 | 123-1 | abc123 | 232753 | NULL | 125707 | IN | NEW |
| 3 | 123-1 | abc123 | 203944 | 224789 | 125707 | OUT | NEW |
| 4 | 123-1 | abc123 | 203944 | NULL | 123332 | IN | NEW |
| 5 | 123-1 | abc123 | 179409 | 198306 | 123332 | OUT | **OLD** |
| 6 | 123-1 | abc123 | 179409 | NULL | 111222 | IN | OLD |
| 7 | 123-1 | **cba999** | 176573 | 171516 | 111222 | OUT | OLD |
| 8 | 123-1 | cba999 | 176573 | NULL | 666000 | IN | OLD |

I have tried to do solve this using `ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Condition`... and doing another ROW_NUMBER() for SerNo then aggregating the data but I can't seem to filter by the first time it changes.

```
    SELECT 
        *,
        CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY Condition ORDER BY TransID ASC)) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END Condition_Change,
        CASE WHEN (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY SerNo ORDER BY TransID ASC)) > 1 THEN 1 ELSE 2 END SerNo_Change
    FROM 
    StkTrans
```

```
    CREATE TABLE StkTrans (
        TransID INT, 
        Part VARCHAR(25), 
        SerNo VARCHAR(25),
        IN_Nr INT, 
        OUT_Nr INT, 
        OrderNr INT, 
        Type    VARCHAR(3),
        Condition VARCHAR(5)
    )
    
    INSERT INTO StkTrans
    (TransID, Part, SerNo, IN_Nr, OUT_Nr, OrderNr, Type, Condition)
    VALUES
    (1, '123-1', 'abc123', 176573, NULL, 666000, 'IN', 'NEW' ),
    (2, '123-1', 'abc123', 176573, 171516, 111222, 'OUT', 'NEW' ),
    (3, '123-1', 'abc123', 179409, NULL, 111222, 'IN', 'NEW' ),
    (4, '123-1', 'abc123', 179409, 198306, 123332, 'OUT', 'NEW' ),
    (5, '123-1', 'abc123', 203944, NULL, 123332, 'IN', 'OLD' ),
    (6, '123-1', 'abc123', 203944, 224789, 125707, 'OUT', 'OLD' ),
    (7, '123-1', 'cba999', 232753, NULL, 125707, 'IN', 'OLD' ),
    (8, '123-1', 'cba999', 232753, 232233, 888777, 'OUT', 'OLD' )
```

Comment: @Austin Yes but the query orders the records with row_number() so I know the order at the time I need to determine which change came first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lead()`.  I'm not sure *exactly* what you are asking.  But to get the rows just before condition changes:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(condition) over (partition by part order by transid) as next_condition
      from t
     ) t
where next_condition <> condition;
```

It is simple to add conditions for other columns as well.